# Arrays frozen in Rails 3.2.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I recently updated a rails app from 3.0.4 to 3.2.4 and I have a strange problem. It seems every array in my app has become frozen. For example if an array gets a set of articles from the database, that array will be instantiated at the first call of the method and will not change. If an article in the array is deleted in the database, it will still refer to it in the array. It only changes if I restart the server. However, when I call array.frozen? it returns false. And when I deploy to heroku I get this error:

!! Unexpected error while processing request: can't modify frozen array

Any suggestions on what might be causing this? I updated another app and didn't run into this problem.

Comment: Please show us how you're getting these sets of articles from the database. We cannot debug a problem if we only have your description and no code to go by.

Comment: @articles = Article.all . I made a scope and the scoped array didn't seem to have this problem. Looks like the problem is anything with .all

Comment: Well I've updated to rails 3.2.6 and that fixed the problem on my end, the arrays are updating like they should and there's no problems. However, I'm still getting the frozen array error on heroku. I submitted a ticket and hopefully we can figure this out. Will post here when we do

Comment: I have the same problem. Everything was find in development with 3.2.2 but then I pushed an update to Heroku and I am getting the same frozen array error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Allright I got it working. I ran `heroku run script/rails console` and it gave me a new error that I hadn't seen yet. Turns out there was a random line of code in my environments/production.rb file that must've been copy and pasted accidentally or something. After removing it, it cleared up the frozen array problem. After some unrelated gem issues, I was able to get my site back online. So my advice is check your production.rb file and run the heroku console.

Comment: haha I read this and thought 'wtf!?' - did it, found my error. Thanks!

Comment: Hmmmm.  Seeing this suddenly today on what is basically a static rails app that hasn't been updated in 2 months.  Will post the ultimate solution here.