# Internal Server Error no matter what I push to heroku app (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git, heroku

I'm having an issue with a ruby on rails app that I have hosted on `Heroku`.
No matter what I push to the repo, I get an `Internal Server Error` string presented to me with no additional information on what I did wrong.

Every change that I decide to make will work great locally, but I can't seem to avoid causes this `Internal Server Error` every time I push. I have to keep rolling back and figure out what I need to fix to make this stop happening.

Does anyone have a suggestion for me?

### Update

I rolled back the repo to a stable changeset, and then I cloned the repo to another directory on my machine.  I made a small change to a javascript file to fix a minor bug, and even that push caused the site to go down and give the `Internal Server Error` message.  Is something wrong with my environment?

### Update 2

For those who have recently gave answers, please review the comments to the question as some of your suggestions have already been addressed.  Thanks!

### Answer:

I'll have to admit that I still don't understand why things were behaving the way they were, but a commit that seemed to be pushed just fine without breaking the site included a ternary operator that Rubymine didn't seem to mind.  After a certain point, every commit caused this `Internal Server Error` thereafter.  But after converting the ternary operator back to an `if-else-end` conditional statement, this behavior ceased.  I hope that this helps someone with a similar issue in the future, albeit obscure.

Comment: Thanks @icodebuster.  Definitely should have made my question prettier.

Comment: perhaps some heroku logs would help. Has this started happening or recently or you have never been able to get Heroku working. Have you run the database migrations on heroku.

Comment: @AlthafHamez this is basically what I think may have caused it, but I don't know how to troubleshoot: I created a new column for a model of mine, and according to PGAdmin III, both local database and master repo's database have the new column (this was a result of running rake db:migrate on local console and running the rake db:migrate command on Heroku.  Does this shine a light on what I might have done to cause this?

Comment: can you post the logs?

Comment: I will.  However, I am new enough to not know how quite yet.  Would you point me in the right direction please?

Comment: `heroku logs` output will be long so you may paste it on pastie.org and link here

Comment: Try the [Getting Started](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby) tutorial if you're new.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a more in-depth look at that tutorial.  I've been developing for several months now, but I've never run into an issue like this where there is little information presented to you in the browser's developer tools.

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel and @jquadrin, here are the results of `heroku logs` http://pastie.org/8144110

Comment: Do you use `freeze` anywhere in your code? Or are you trying to modify params or something? Problem is `!! Unexpected error while processing request: can't modify frozen array` but I never seen this error before

Comment: Yea I haven't either.  I'll take a look when I get off work.

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel, no usage of freeze found in Project :(  Any other troubleshooting suggestions?

Comment: And in development everything is ok?

Comment: I am able to run my application on my local machine.  This started when I added a new column to a particular table.  Is there anything I can do to see if this might be the cause of the issue?

Comment: Have you seen this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990051/arrays-frozen-in-rails-3-2-4 ?

Comment: looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990051/arrays-frozen-in-rails-3-2-4 is way to go.

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev and @SantoshPingale, I saw this one.  I tried running the command `heroku run script/rails console` as suggested in the question you shared with me as a link.  I did not receive an additional error message like @Ultimation did.  I'll keep this one in mind still though...Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The main problem I see from the logs is

```
!! Unexpected error while processing request: can't modify frozen array
```

A quick Google search for "rails production can't modify frozen array" gave this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990051/arrays-frozen-in-rails-3-2-4) on SO (also about heroku.)

Other things you can do:

1. Run `heroku run script/rails console` and look out for errors.
2. Install postgresql on your development machine and do a entire test run in production mode. This means running `rake db:load_schema`, `rake assets:precompile`, and `rails s` with the `RAILS_ENV=production` prefix. Make sure you are using `thin`.
3. Start a VM that mirrors Heroku's setup, do number 2 with [Foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman).
4. Sign up for Airbrake and check the errors.

(Actually if you did 3. and it still works on your local machine, it's time to contact Heroku support.)

#### Last Resort: Binary Search

Let's call your current repo `project.git`. Make a copy of this repo, and rename the master branch to `future`. Checkout the earliest working commit of `future` into the master branch of your new repo, and create a new Heroku app. Push and test.

1. If no errors, jump forward to the midpoint.
2. If there is an error, jump backwards.
3. Push and test. Repeat.

Keeping doing that until you find the exact commit that introduced the bug. This takes a long time. [git bisect](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Debugging-with-Git#Binary-Search) might be useful.

Comment: Thanks @JimLim, I have tried all those steps.  No additional errors given.

Comment: Wow. This is tough. I am updating my answer with a last resort technique.

Comment: It seems to be when I added a particular controller method.  I'm looking line by line to see if I can see anything...

Comment: I have determined it was a ternary operator that Rubymine didn't seem to mind.  When I changed the structure of the conditional statement I was making back to the `if-else-end` structure, any and all pushes that I made afterward did not cause the `Internal Server Error`!

Comment: Glad you solved it. This is really strange, since it sounds like a Ruby syntax concern than a Rubymine/Heroku concern. Will you send me an email with the exact details? I would like to investigate (just out of curiosity.)

Comment: yea I can do that.  It will have to wait until late tonight, as I won't have access to my machine until then.  Sorry for the delay.  But speaking with one of my friends working with me on this project, he thought it had to do with the fact that my ternary operator was on multiple lines too (trying to keep it readable without having to scroll left and right).  He also thought that this ternary operator was being converted back to an `if-else-end` statement during compilation anyway, so I was just creating more work.

Answer (score 1):

In your terminal, run
heroku logs --tail
Then from other terminal run the push command and see what is going on

Comment: Thanks @obenda.  You did read the comments on the original question right?

Answer (score 0):

If rails console on the heroku server works, then Rails seems to be booting up okay ?

Did you actually run rails console on heroku without errors, or just the same error ?

Have you tried running the rails server on production mode locally ?

```
rails server -e production
```

Personally, instead of hunting around with no extra information other than Internal Server Error, I'll make sure that I'm signed up to an error service like Airbrake [1] or setup Exception Notifier [2]

[1] https://addons.heroku.com/airbrake

[2] https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification